# В массив не записывается предложение

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Ни scanf, ни cin, ни gets_s не помогает. Просит ввести первое предложение, ввожу, и сразу же прыгает через все остальные, без возможности что то записать в них. Что не так?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

struct sent
{
    char mes[256];
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    system("color f0");
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");

    sent mas[10];

    int nos = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of the sentences:" << endl;
    cin >> nos;

    for (int i = 0; i < nos; i++)
    {
        mas[i].num = i;
        cout << "Enter the " << i+1 << " sentence:" << endl;
        gets_s(mas[i].mes);     
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nos; i++)
    {
        puts(mas[i].mes);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то выдумываете. Никакого "прыгает через все остальные" тут не будет.

Это код будет "перепрыгивать" только через ввод *первого* предложения. Потому что после `cin >> nos;` у вас во входном буфере осталось сидеть непрочитанное `\n`. И это `\n` будет сразу воспринято следующим `gets_s(mas[i].mes);` как ввод пустого предложения.

Все остальные предложения после первого вводятся нормально, никаких перепрыгиваний.

Все работает именно так, как и должно работать.

---

Решить проблему "перепрыгивания" ввода первого предложения можно разными способами (тема уже много раз освещалась), но я бы рекомендовал вам просто не смешивать форматированный ввод и построчный ввод. Примените построчный везде

```
char number[64];
cout << "Enter number of the sentences:" << endl;
gets_s(number);
int nos = std::stoi(number);
```